# How to combine two filters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have circle, triangle, square in four color, each this shape have own value
I want to make filter for shape, color and numerical range.
this is code for filter html:

```
     <div class="searchColor" id="filterColor">
             Color: <br/>
            <input type="checkbox"  id="Red"  value="Red" />Red                <br/>
            <input type="checkbox"  id="Blue"   value="Blue"/>Blue                <br/>
            <input type="checkbox"  id="Green"  value="Green"/>Green                <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Gold"   value="Gold"/>Gold                <p/>
        </div>
        <div class="searchColor" id="searchShape">
           Shape:<br/>
            <div class="paintSelect">
                <input type="checkbox" id="triangle"  value="triangle" />triangle                    <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id="circle"  value="circle"/>circle                    <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id="square" value="square"/>square
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="searchSelectedNumber" id="searchNumber">
           Number:<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id="number01"  value="1" />10-30
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id="number02"  value="2"/>20-40

        </div>
```

This code for JS.

```
  var arrayNumber = [];
var arrayMax = [];

$("div[class='searchSelectedNumber'] input").change(function () {
    arrayMax = $("[class^=number]");
    for (i=0; i<arrayMax.length; i++){
        arrayNumber[i] = arrayMax[i].innerHTML;
    }
    var firstIntervalStart = 0;
    var firstIntervalEnd = 0;
    var secondIntervalStart = 0;
    var secondIntervalEnd = 0;
    if (  $("#searchNumber input:checked").length == 0){
        $('.color').show();
    } else {
        var oneChecked = $("#number01").is(':checked');
        var twoChecked = $("#number02").is(':checked');

        if (oneChecked) {
            firstIntervalStart = 0;
            firstIntervalEnd = 30;
            if (twoChecked) {
                firstIntervalEnd = 40;
            }
        }
        else if (twoChecked) {
            firstIntervalStart = 20;
            firstIntervalEnd = 40;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < arrayMax.length; i++) {
            if (arrayNumber[i] > firstIntervalStart && arrayNumber[i] <= firstIntervalEnd) {
                $($(".color")[i]).show();
            } else {
                $($(".color")[i]).hide();
            }
        }
        if (secondIntervalStart != 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < arrayMax.length; i++) {
                if (arrayNumber[i] > secondIntervalStart && arrayNumber[i] <= secondIntervalEnd) {
                    console.log("secondIntervalStart < arrayPrice[i] <= secondIntervalEnd " + $($(".color")[i]));
                    $($(".color")[i]).show();
                } else {
                    $($(".color")[i]).hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
$("div[class='searchColor'] input").change(function () {

    if($("#filterColor input:checked").length == 0 && $("#searchShape input:checked").length == 0
      ){
        $('.color').show();
    }else if($("#filterColor input:checked").length == 0 && $("#searchShape input:checked").length > 0){
        $('.color').show();
        $("#searchShape input:not(:checked)").each(function() {
            var k = $(this).val();
            $('.' + k).hide();
        });
    }else if($("#filterColor input:checked").length > 0 && $("#searchShape input:checked").length == 0){
        $('.color').show();
        $("#filterColor input:not(:checked)").each(function() {

            $('.' + $(this).attr('value')).hide();
        });
    }else{
        $('.color').show();

        $("#searchShape input:not(:checked)").each(function() {
            $('.' + $(this).attr('value')).hide();
        });

        $("#filterColor input:not(:checked)").each(function() {
            $('.' + $(this).attr('value')).hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Code is working, but the numerical range code works separately from color and shape. And I don't understand how to force this script to work together.
 When I select numeric range and shape or color(or together color and shape) I want to see this shape or color in the numeric range. I try the many varients, but no one variant not work. 
This link on example that I have
[jsfiddle.net/this my code](https://jsfiddle.net/Magnit/y2b3qebr/21/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine multiple FIlters together to filter Task Rows using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994081/how-to-combine-multiple-filters-together-to-filter-task-rows-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the number of filters increases you need to check various possibility as you have three filters here conditions is :

1. None of the filter is selected
2. Any one filter is selected
3. All the filter is selected

   ```
     if(color.length == 0 && shape.length == 0 && number.length > 0){

        showEle(number)
     }else if(color.length == 0 && shape.length > 0 && number.length == 0){

        showEle(shape)
     }else if(color.length > 0 && shape.length == 0 && number.length == 0){

        showEle(color)
     }else if(color.length > 0 && shape.length > 0 && number.length == 0){
       var temp = [];
       color.forEach(function(oe){
           shape.forEach(function(ie){
           temp.push(oe +"."+ie);  
         });
       });
       showEle(temp);
     }else if(color.length == 0 && shape.length > 0 && number.length > 0){
       var temp = [];
       shape.forEach(function(oe){
           number.forEach(function(ie){
           temp.push(oe +"."+ie);  
         });
       });
       showEle(temp);
     }else if(color.length > 0 && shape.length == 0 && number.length > 0){
       var temp = [];
       color.forEach(function(oe){
           number.forEach(function(ie){
           temp.push(oe +"."+ie);  
         });
       });
       showEle(temp);
     }else{
       var temp = [];
       color.forEach(function(oe){
           number.forEach(function(ie){
           shape.forEach(function(iie){
               temp.push(oe +"."+ie + "." + iie);
           });
         });
       });
       showEle(temp);
     }
   ```

See this fiddle for more info  https://jsfiddle.net/y2b3qebr/23/

Comment: if I will recive digital value from DB how do this variant?

Comment: @Viking please elaborate you question

Comment: If I recive number from DB in Numeric(19,2) type. This code not work, becouse I recive in `*.**` format. I try to make
` var array = ["22.22", "11.11", "33.33", "44.44"];`
var result = $.map(array, function(el){
    return el.replace(/\./, '\\\\.');
});'  Becouse I read `id=name.lastName` = in jquery `$("#name\\.lastName")` but it's no work

Comment: @Viking Can you reproduce it in fiddle with your db data

Comment: @Viking the first thing is class name containing dot must need escaped moreover 10.10 while comparing will become 10.1 whereas in string class it will remain 10.10

Comment: @Viking you can do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/jndzw1y9/2/ where . is replaced by - else if you want to use dot then escape by http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thank you for the all your answers.I recive from DB this array `<div class="color" th:classappend="${model.color} +' '+ ${model.shape}+ ' ' +${model.number}">` In your example, you change 10.10 on 10-10. And I can't change info in DB

Comment: True you cannot change info in db but can do a split and join here in ui else use the dot notation but remember to escape it by 2 slash aa doc says

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I try do it [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Magnit/y2b3qebr/26/) with your code, but it's no go

Comment: @Viking tehre you go https://jsfiddle.net/jndzw1y9/3/ reference from https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/ :)

Comment: Could you be so kind to explaine me one part from your code? `if(price.indexOf(ele) == -1)
                        price.push(ele);`

Comment: Im checking that i dont insert duplicate elements because a number say 25 can be in 0 to 30 and 20 to 40 as well