# Combine multiple filter in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw similar question in this thread but I cannot used the comment since I'm just new user: [How to combine multiple FIlters together to filter Task Rows using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994081/how-to-combine-multiple-filters-together-to-filter-task-rows-using-jquery)

Here's the live demo. I just want to know on how to do instead of using full string search, it should be only "Contains" of the input text.

```
(function () {
  var
    filters = {
      user: null,
      status: null,
      milestone: null,
      priority: null,
      tags: null
    };

  function updateFilters() {
    $('.task-list-row').hide().filter(function () {
      var
        self = $(this),
        result = true; // not guilty until proven guilty

      Object.keys(filters).forEach(function (filter) {
        if (filters[filter] && (filters[filter] != 'None') && (filters[filter] != 'Any')) {
          result = result && filters[filter] === self.data(filter);
        }
      });

      return result;
    }).show();
  }

  function bindDropdownFilters() {
    Object.keys(filters).forEach(function (filterName) {
      $('#' + filterName + '-filter').on('change', function () {
        filters[filterName] = this.value;
        updateFilters();
      });
    });
  }

  bindDropdownFilters();
})();
```

http://codepen.io/luciopaiva/pen/YXYGaY?editors=101

Comment: Try [`String#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) or [`String#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: May be this will help you, `$(this).data('milestone').includes(taskMilestone)`

Comment: Sorry @charlietfl I updated my code I've encoded wrong source code. Where should I put that?

Comment: Sorry @Madhavan.V I updated my code I've encoded wrong source code. Where should I put that?